# How can I put multiple elements into ‘elem’

Tags: haskell

Let’s say I want to do something like`` "ace" `elem` "abcdefg" ``. Of course we can’t because you need a list of the first elements type. Instead is there a way we could turn this into taking every char in "ace" and comparing them individually with "abcdefg", then using or statements to combine them, but without manually doing this (because in my program it’s a variable of unknown length and characters).

Comment: So presumably you want the result of ``"ace" `mElem` "abcdefg"`` to be `True`, but what about e.g. ``"aze" `mElem` "abcdefg"``? Always give examples with expected results when asking such a question.

Comment: Consider the type of ``map (`elem` "abcdefg") "abc"``. and think how you might use the functions `and` or `or`.

Comment: True, because a and e still are in it, like an or gate rather than an and gate.

Comment: `any (\`elem\` "abcdefg") "ace"`. The type of `any` is `Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`. For your purposes, consider it specialised to `(Char -> Bool) -> String -> Bool`

Comment: Vikstapolis this is exactily what I needed. Could you make it a answer instead of a comment pls? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like leftaroundabout has already posted an answer - why don't you just accept that. Also, as he mentioned, Hoogle is a great tool, so always try using it when you know the type of the function you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a specific case of a more general problem: you have a function `Char -> Bool` (or `a -> Bool`) and you want to adapt it as a function `[a] -> Bool`. In other words, what you need is a function

```
adaptOr :: (a -> Bool) -> ([a] -> Bool)
```

Well, that's actually something you can [ask Hoogle about](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Bool%29+-%3E+%28%5Ba%5D+-%3E+Bool%29)! The first hits are

```
any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
base GHC.List GHC.OldList
Applied to a predicate and a list, any determines if any element of the list satisfies the predicate. For the result to be False, the list must be finite; True, however, results from a True value for the predicate applied to an element at a finite index of a finite or infinite list.

>>> any (> 3) []
False

>>> any (> 3) [1,2]
False

>>> any (> 3) [1,2,3,4,5]
True

>>> any (> 3) [1..]
True

>>> any (> 3) [0, -1..]
* Hangs forever *

all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
base GHC.List GHC.OldList
Applied to a predicate and a list, all determines if all elements of the list satisfy the predicate. For the result to be True, the list must be finite; False, however, results from a False value for the predicate applied to an element at a finite index of a finite or infinite list.

>>> all (> 3) []
True

>>> all (> 3) [1,2]
False

>>> all (> 3) [1,2,3,4,5]
False

>>> all (> 3) [1..]
False

>>> all (> 3) [4..]
* Hangs forever *
```

Now you need to think which of these is right for your case, and then use it accordingly. You want

```
  all⁄any (\c -> c`elem`"abcdefg") "ace"
```

This can also be written with an infix section:

```
  all⁄any (`elem`"abcdefg") "ace"
```

Comment: Note that while Hoogle shows `any` as being defined in `GHC.List` when you search for it by this type, a version of it generalised to all `Foldable`s is available in `Prelude` itself (as well as `Data.List` and `Data.Foldable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's using that `or` statement as you wanted:

```
or [c `elem` "abcdefg" | c <- "ace"]
```

How to come up with this?

You already know that you want

```
  'a' `elem` "abcdefg" ||
  'c' `elem` "abcdefg" ||
  'e' `elem` "abcdefg"
```

and the type of `(||)` is `Bool -> Bool -> Bool`.

But you have a *list* of the characters to test. And after you've tested each of them, you'll have the *list* of Boolean results. Thus you want a function of type `[Bool] -> Bool`.

[Hoogle time!](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5BBool%5D%20-%3E%20Bool)